# How can I set a default value on a projection field?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a projection DAC defined as below. I am using this DAC in a view on `InventoryItemMaint`. I need the `InventoryID` field of my projection DAC to default to the current item's ID, but nothing I try works.

Is there a special way to do this?

I've tried:

- `PXDBDefault` with `PXParent`
- `PXDefault(typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryID))]`
- `PXFormula` (like below)

```
[PXProjection(typeof(SelectFrom<MXFormulaClass>.InnerJoin<MXFormulaClassNutrients>.
    On<MXFormulaClassNutrients.classID.IsEqual<MXFormulaClass.classID>>.
    LeftJoin<MXNutrientValue>.
    On<MXNutrientValue.nutrientID.IsEqual<MXFormulaClassNutrients.nutrientID>>), Persistent = true)]
[PXCacheName("MXItemNutrientValues")]
public class MXItemNutrientValues : IBqlTable
{      
    #region ClassID
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(MXFormulaClassNutrients.classID))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Class ID")]
    public virtual int? ClassID { get; set; }
    public abstract class classID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<classID> { }
    #endregion

    #region NutrientID
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(MXFormulaClassNutrients.nutrientID))]
    [PXExtraKey]
    [PXDBDefault(typeof(MXFormulaClassNutrients.nutrientID))]
    [PXSelector(typeof(MXNutrient.nutrientID),
        typeof(MXNutrient.nutrientCD),
        typeof(MXNutrient.description),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(MXNutrient.nutrientCD),
        DescriptionField = typeof(MXNutrient.description))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Nutrient")]
    public virtual int? NutrientID { get; set; }
    public abstract class nutrientID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<nutrientID> { }
    #endregion

    #region MinMax
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(MXFormulaClassNutrients.minMax))]
    [PXIntList(new int[] { 1, 2 }, new string[] { "Min", "Max" })]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Min/Max")]
    public virtual int? MinMax { get; set; }
    public abstract class minMax : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<minMax> { }
    #endregion

    #region SortOrder
    [PXDBInt(BqlField = typeof(MXFormulaClassNutrients.sortOrder))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Sort Order")]
    public virtual int? SortOrder { get; set; }
    public abstract class sortOrder : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<sortOrder> { }
    #endregion

    #region InventoryID
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(MXNutrientValue.inventoryID))]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory ID")]
    public virtual int? InventoryID { get; set; }
    public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<inventoryID> { }
    #endregion

    #region Value
    [PXDBDecimal(BqlField = typeof(MXNutrientValue.value))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Value")]
    public virtual Decimal? Value { get; set; }
    public abstract class value : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<value> { }
    #endregion

    #region CreatedByID
    [PXDBCreatedByID(BqlField = typeof(MXNutrientValue.createdByID))]
    public virtual Guid? CreatedByID { get; set; }
    public abstract class createdByID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<createdByID> { }
    #endregion

    #region CreatedByScreenID
    [PXDBCreatedByScreenID(BqlField = typeof(MXNutrientValue.createdByScreenID))]
    public virtual string CreatedByScreenID { get; set; }
    public abstract class createdByScreenID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<createdByScreenID> { }
    #endregion

    #region CreatedDateTime
    [PXDBCreatedDateTime(BqlField = typeof(MXNutrientValue.createdDateTime))]
    public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public abstract class createdDateTime : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<createdDateTime> { }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedByID
    [PXDBLastModifiedByID(BqlField = typeof(MXNutrientValue.lastModifiedByID))]
    public virtual Guid? LastModifiedByID { get; set; }
    public abstract class lastModifiedByID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<lastModifiedByID> { }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedByScreenID
    [PXDBLastModifiedByScreenID(BqlField = typeof(MXNutrientValue.lastModifiedByScreenID))]
    public virtual string LastModifiedByScreenID { get; set; }
    public abstract class lastModifiedByScreenID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<lastModifiedByScreenID> { }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedDateTime
    [PXDBLastModifiedDateTime(BqlField = typeof(MXNutrientValue.lastModifiedDateTime))]
    public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public abstract class lastModifiedDateTime : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<lastModifiedDateTime> { }
    #endregion

    #region Tstamp
    [PXDBTimestamp(BqlField = typeof(MXNutrientValue.tstamp))]
    public virtual byte[] Tstamp { get; set; }
    public abstract class tstamp : PX.Data.BQL.BqlByteArray.Field<tstamp> { }
    #endregion

    #region Noteid
    [PXNote(BqlField = typeof(MXNutrientValue.noteid))]
    public virtual Guid? Noteid { get; set; }
    public abstract class noteid : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<noteid> { }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking your view to the Current property of the cache in the view definition in the InventoryMaint graph extension?  Something like

```
public PXSelect<MXItemNutrientValues,Where<MXItemNutrientValues.inventoryid, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>> customView;
```

Comment: Yes, but ``Where<MXItemNutrientValues.classID.IsEqual<InventoryItemExt.usrFormulaClassID.FromCurrent>>``

Comment: Interesting, I know the Current property only covers the Base DAC of the View.  Perhaps that doesn't include cache extensions.